# Move parameter "state" after parameters without default value in Sonarqube

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, sonarqube

I'm getting this error 'Move parameter "state" after parameters without default value' in React native Sonarqube, please help me to resolve this error

```
const initialState = {
  onVerify: null,
  showCaptcha: false,
};
export default function googleReCaptchaReducer(state = initialState, action){
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you try applying the suggestion? 
`export default function googleReCaptchaReducer(action, state = initialState){
}`

Comment: @SakisTsalk yes I tried, but the library is expecting state as first parameter

Answer (score 0):

I think Sonarqube want to switch between state and action parameters because with declare `state = initialState` that means state is optional parameter.

In this case, I think you don't need set initialState for state parameter. If you are using useReducer, I would suggest follow useReducer example of reactjs.org

```
const initialState = {count: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```